# Split by certain pattern in python

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone i have a pattern (using django)

```
[[u'13'], [u'12', u'23'], [u'30', u'31']]
```

and i want to spilt this and want to append into a list
like `[13,12,23,30,31]`
I know this can be done using regular expression but unable to make regualr expression for that.
Please help into this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean *"a pattern"*? That looks like a list of lists of strings, why do you think you need a regex?

Comment: Yes jon it is a list of lists. but i want a single list of containing all values.

Comment: So you want to *flatten* the list, try searching for that. But it doesn't need a regular expression.

Comment: Here we go... `list(itertools.chain(*x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ast` library in order to make the string a python list.

After, iterate through the list and chain all items into one list.

```
import ast

st = "[[u'13'], [u'12', u'23'], [u'30', u'31']]"

li = ast.literal_eval(st) # you can use this library in order to make the string a python list.
new_li = [item for inner_list in li for item in inner_list]

print (new_li)
```

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python literal or container display.

Comment: Why would you special case lists of a certain length when flattening?

Comment: @jonrsharpe , No need, I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Omri it is showing error `malformed string`

Comment: Thanks...it is working

Answer (score 0):

You could do in python3,

```
In [8]: [int(s) for i in a for s in i]
Out[8]: [13, 12, 23, 30, 31]
```

Comment: i am using python 2.7